# Liferay portlet-resource permission

Tags: permissions, liferay

How to create a portlet-resource permission for my custom portlet? I wanted specific users to view my custom portlet not all of the users.

Admin: View-able

User1: not view-able

User2: View-able

How can I achieve this? Any hint?

I've tried the wiki but no luck.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using liferay service builder in your custom portlet ?

Comment: Yes. I will be using service builder in my custom portlets.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a portlet-resource permission - "VIEW" is already a permission.

Just give the user that may see the portlet a specific role. In the permissions configuration of the portlet on a page you can then remove the VIEW permissions for all other roles.